# unusual space between paragraphs

Tags: paragraphs

I am writing a thesis document in Latex. I have already written several pages in it but suddenly at one page the spacing between paragraphs is too much (3-4 lines).

As its a long documents so, its a bit difficult for me to provide the working example. I was wondering if somebody has also faced the similar problem or know the possible reason of this weird results.

By the was, I am writing the paragraphs in the **following way**:

```
Here the para-1 ends. 

The para-2 begins here after a gap of one line. Now, it ENDS here.

Para-3 has started with a gap of one line.
```

**PS:** it is a single sided document

**UPDATE:**

I have found that if I remove the line below the equation then everything become ok but if i put the line below the equation then, the problem of weird spacing comes. I have used the same method of putting equation and paragraphs in other sections but did not face any problem.

```
\begin{gather}
\text{positional distance component, } d_p(i,j) = \sqrt{            (   n_x^i - n_x^j   )^2 + ( n_y^i - n_y^j   )^2     } \\
\text{and color distance component, } d_c(i,j) = \sqrt{         (   n_L^i - n_L^j   )^2 + ( n_a^i - n_a^j   )^2 + ( n_b^i - n_b^j   )^2     }
\end{gather}

The weightage of the two distance components can be varied by chaning the value of two multiplying constants ($\mathit{w_p}$ and $\mathit{w_c}$) for position and color components of distance measure.
```

Comment: Are you perhaps using `\begin{figure}[H]` (or `table`)?

Comment: no, nothing in this section.

Comment: Do you have a `center` environment around a figure-environment?

Comment: Is your document two sided and `flushbottom` is active?

Comment: yes, but it is another section. In this current section, I just have text only.

Comment: It might be working with `\flushbottom` (or equivalent) if the document is in two-sided mode.  You can try `\raggedbottom` and see if that 'fixes' it. Note, however, that the bottoms of pages will not all end at the same place.

Comment: It is a single sided document

Comment: Also note that the cause of what you are seeing on one page may be due to a variety of factors from another page or pages....

Comment: It is not a single-sided document according to your most recent edit: you have the option `twoside` listed.

Comment: @jon: Sorry, I meant that it not the double column document like in research papers.

Comment: [Minimale Vorlage vs. maximale Probleme](http://www.komascript.de/latexvorlage) and [LaTeX Vorlagen](http://niederberger.com.de/latex-vorlagen). Some of your options for KOMA-script are obsolete making it switch within a compatibility mode. Lots of stuff that got fixed in later versions remains unfixed in compat mode. Where is that template from?

Comment: you didn't answer if putting `\raggedbottom` in the preamble solves the issue.

Comment: Now we have even less information. Please try to prepare a minimal working example. As you are apparently german, a link to the german instructions: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/569/was-ist-ein-vollstandiges-minimalbeispiel-oder-kurz-vm-und-wie-erstelle-ich-dieses

Comment: @skm the update doesn't address the question asked in the above comment. Also adding or removing the blank line after the display changes the meaning (and usually layout) if the following text is a new paragraph the blank line is needed, if it is not, the blank line is wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The problem is, the space between all the paragraphs becomes weird on the page where I have put the equation.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: \raggedbottom has solved the problem but I dont understand why the combination of equation and paragraph of text created problem on this particular page.

Comment: skm, we are not psychic ;-) We cannot know what is going on on your page. That's why we are asking for (compilable) code examples, to the same as you see.

Comment: @Johannes_B: yes, i clearly understand your point and that's why I have mentioned in my question that it is a bit difficult to provide the working example. And, even if I proved, I dont think that the same problem will come because the problem does not exist at rest of the pages (around 20 pages)

Comment: @Johannes_B: I have already mentioned in my previous comments that \raggedbottom has solved the problem. Thanks to the wonderful community :)

Comment: @skm -- one more question: does the next page start with something like a section heading or a multi-line display that would require some "minimum available space" at the bottom of a page?  if that's the case, then just the tiny amount of extra space difference between a display ending a paragraph and one fully embedded in a paragraph could push the "overlong" bit over to the next page, and the space following a paragraph ending with a display is (usually) an "ideal" place to stretch the space.  (that's why `\raggedborrom` solves the problem -- it suppresses the stretch.)

Comment: Note it isn't really a "problem" at all, the class specifies that the bottom row of each page should be at the same point, and that is achieved by stretching white space at points where that is allowed. So if the page is short of material the white space gets stretched, that is by design, not a bug.